# Variance of estimated sample mean

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, standard-error, mean

On Page 65 of the book - Introduction to Statistical Learning (https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/ISLR_print1.pdf#page=80), I got a little confused on the Standard Error formula of $\hat{μ}$ as described below.

$$Var(\hat{μ}) = {SE(\hat{μ})}^2 =σ^2/n,$$ where σ is the standard deviation of each of the realizations $y_{i}$ of Y

In my understanding, I feel that σ must be the standard deviation of $\hat{μ}$  and not of each of the realizations $y_{i}$ of Y.

Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of their variances. Also note that $Var(Ax)=A^2Var(x)$ for some constant $A$ and random $x$. So if ${y_i}$ are iid with variance $\sigma ^2$ then $Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum y_i) =\frac{1}{n^2} \sum Var(y_i)=\frac{1}{n^2} n Var(y_i)= \frac{1}{n} Var(y_i)$